# Sending Email with attachment by MS-Outlook in VBA, Excel when Outlook is closed

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

When I send mail free from attachment, works truly.

But when I using the `.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName` parameter, it does not send and been pending to opening Outlook.

**I want send mails when outlook is closed.**

I'm using below code:

```
Sub SendMail()
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With OutlookMail
        .To = "address@domain.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "M"
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = "Hi, <p> I'm sending this message from Excel using VBA.</p>Please find <strong> M</strong> in life."
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("n", 1, Now)
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        .ReadReceiptRequested = True
        .Send
    End With
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

About `.DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("n", 1, Now)`: I want the email have send 1 minutes after running the macro.

Regards.

Reasons for why this question is unique:

1. [StackowerflowQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14236696/9075944): Here the problem is solved in my above code and the remained problem is **sending attachment** that I focused on here.  and the appropriated answer is what I accent about is **Outlook is closed.**

### Update

Another symptom is when I running above code an temporal Icon will shown in the try system with a popup message: `"another program is using outlook. to disconnect program and exit outlook..."`.

Please also consider this, if important.

---

Please note that the problem is **sending attachment**.

With above code, the problem of sending email when outlook is closed was solved. (that mentioned in similar question)

So the remained problem is **sending attachment** in this case (Outlook is closed).

Comment: With regards, My I was search and read all of similar questions. My question is not duplicated, because: The problem is in sending `Attachment` when Outlook is closed, while Emails that are free attachment have send truly. And the focus here is on sending attachment problem. with great thanks of your attention.

Comment: With regards, I bold that because noting about the accepted answer of similar question.I was reviewed these similar questions before. As you mentioned me, I specified the file path with `ActiveWorkbook.FullName` next to the `Attachment` line.

Comment: Just to check with you, when you are sending the email, is the excel opened?

Comment: Yes. I'm try your answer now. So When I try to send current opened workbook when Outlook is opened, It's work truly. But when Outlook is closed and I'm try to send attachment, Its been pending to when opening Outlook.

Comment: @ppz, with regards, Please if I have succeed to explain why my question is not duplicated and have answer before, revise the tag that shown above my question as **This question may already have an answer here:...**

Comment: To be honest with you, it still looks duplicate to me. By adding attachments does not really differentiate much.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you can accept and raises new question about the attachment. You can try my first answer( copy as ) for attachment.

Comment: I would recommend you to check your Path to Ensure that you had the “”. I tried print that path out and it does not have the double column.

Comment: I tried to made my question more clear as you advised me. The question is about **attachment sending issue**, originally. I researched about before and asked this question with attention to similar previous questions  as you guide me, so because that I made my question involved previous similar questions and answers notes. I did you recommend me so what you advised works truly only when outlook is open in case of attachment involving for mail. (`.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName` code line above). Indeed I tried this: (`.Attachments.Add  "C:\test.xlsm"`) for a closed workbook as you...

Comment: ...advised me in previous answer, but same as before, the problem of sending email with attachment is remained, as 1) when the Outlook is ** closed** the email with no attachment send truly, but when it consist attachment, the email been pended to when opening outlook.  2) When the Outlook is **opened**, the email send truly in each two. **I need send email with attachment when Outlook is closed**

Comment: I had just test the code for with attachment and without attachment. Both of them works when outlook is closed.

Comment: Use .Display before adding attachment

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misinterpreted your question just now. With reference to [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?36205-Solved-Can-t-VBA-send-emails-when-Outlook-is-not-opened), you need to add the following code.

```
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application 
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem

On Error Resume Next 
Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") 
If OutApp Is Nothing Then 
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
End If 
On Error Goto 0 

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
With OutMail 
    .To = "address@domain.com" ' continue from here
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem remainds. I tried what you advised me, but when Outlook is closed, sending attachment is been pending.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: ***UPDATE...*** Regards you, Your answer is right and works when the Outlook is **closed** for the case of *sending mail **without** attachment*. Unfortunately the problem is remains. Please review the original question again, that's involved the code is pretty similar above answer and this two have works truly in case of the Outlook is **closed** for sending mail **without attachment**, but please advise me How can solve the problem of **sending mails with attachment when Outlook is closed?** I have updated my question by referring a symptom may related to the issue.